# How do I split a string and store it in a list?

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a string `a="100111"` and want to split it and store as `b=("1","0","0","1","1","1")` as  a list with length =6. I tried splitting using srtsplit but I end up with a list `b = ("1" "0" "0" "1" "1" "1")`, with length = 1. The end goal is to get which positions in the string `"100111"` has 1. For example when I split a and store it in b as `("1","0","0","1","1","1")` and then use `which(b=='1')` it want to get `(1,4,5,6)`

Comment: `which(unlist(strsplit(a, split="")) == 1)` will do it. you have to pull the vector out of the list with `unlist`.

Answer (score 5):

`gregexpr` will give the positions of 1's in the string without having to actually split it:

```
unlist(gregexpr("1", "100111"))
## [1] 1 4 5 6
```

Comment: Nice. I Keep forgetting about those regex functions.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `str_locate` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_locate_all(a, "1")[[1]][,1]
#[1] 1 4 5 6
```